# xcode stream fail to play on iphone

Tags: xcode, swift, http-live-streaming, akamai

I'm developing a iptv for ios devices. So far i can play a list of channels. Deployment target is 8.0. I have tested with iphone s5 virtual device and i can play the stream correctly. i decided to test it on a real device. 
The application run perfectly but the stream wont open. screen remains black. How is it possible i cant open streams in real device when virtual devices do? Here is my code.

```
func play(var currentChannel:TVChannel){

    moviePlayer?.stop();

    var URL:String = currentChannel.channelUrl;
    var _URL = Encryption().Decrypt(plainText: URL);
    var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: _URL)!

    println(url);

    moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
    moviePlayer?.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None;

    if(db.select.getStringValue(forKey: db.STRING_VALUE_CURRENT_CHANNEL) == nil){
        db.insert.CoreData_Insert(value: "-1", coreDataKey: db.STRING_VALUE_CURRENT_CHANNEL)
    }
    //send log
    Logs().sendHit(currentChannel.channelNumber, accessway: access_way, lastchannel: db.select.getStringValue(forKey: db.STRING_VALUE_CURRENT_CHANNEL).value, username: db.select.getStringValue(forKey: db.STRING_VALUE_USERNAME).value);

    db.delete.deleteEntityFromCore(entityName: "StringValue", field_Name: "key", field_Value: db.STRING_VALUE_CURRENT_CHANNEL);

    //save the new channel

    db.insert.CoreData_Insert(value: currentChannel.channelNumber, coreDataKey: db.STRING_VALUE_CURRENT_CHANNEL);

    if let player = moviePlayer{

        player.view.frame = self.view.bounds
        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.scalingMode = .AspectFill
        self.view.addSubview(player.view)
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(two_way_channel);
        player.play();

    }
    self.updateOSD();


}
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code run perfectly, my problem was that CDN (akamai) had a restriction for user agent of the client who asked for a channel stream. Somehow the virtual device user agent could pass the restriction. This happens because probably iphone s5 real device and iphone s5 virtual device have different user agent.